# How to keep duplicates from being added to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var reservations = [];

function addReservation() {
    //Gets Input from textboxes. 
    var nameChosen = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
    var roomChosen = document.getElementById("selRoom").value; 

    //adds input into the array.
    reservations[reservations.length] = roomChosen + " ";
    reservations[reservations.length] = nameChosen + " ";

    //Gets input from radio button.
    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName("Day[]").length; i++) {             
        if (document.getElementsByName("Day[]")[i].checked) {
            reservations.push(document.getElementsByName("Day[]")[i].value);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName("Time[]").length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementsByName("Time[]")[i].checked) {
            reservations.push(document.getElementsByName("Time[]")[i].value);   
        }
    }                   
}
```

How do I ensure that if the time and day cannot be added twice to the array?
Or easier yet, How do I ensure that the same name cannot be added twice to the array?

Comment: You could check if the value is already included before pushing, filter duplicated at the end, or use a [Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for a way to break out of the `for` loop after you hit the first match. One way to do this is to set `i` to the termination condition inside the `if` statement, which will exit the loop.

```
//Gets input from radio button.
for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName("Day[]").length; i++) {             
    if (document.getElementsByName("Day[]")[i].checked) {
        reservations.push(document.getElementsByName("Day[]")[i].value);
        i = document.getElementsByName("Day[]").length
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName("Time[]").length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementsByName("Time[]")[i].checked) {
        reservations.push(document.getElementsByName("Time[]")[i].value);
        i = document.getElementsByName("Time[]").length
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Test if the item is in the array first

```
if (!item in array) { array.push(item); }
```